# how to insert date in MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

i am developing window application using visual studio and c#
i want to insert date in Mysql database table which having datatype date

using datetimepicker control of visual studio

i wrote an insert query like this (`insert into table name values('"+ datetimepicker.value + "'`)

it give me following error

```
ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.1.47-community]Incorrect datetime value: '01-06-2010 00:00:00' for column 'Date' at row 1
```

can any one resolve this problem

Comment: You need to use an ISO 8601 formatted date (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS), eg: "2010-06-02 12:34:56". I'm not supplying this as an answer because I don't know how to reformat the date in c#

Comment: thanks but how to use it in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Mysql DATE() datatype have the Format: YYYY-MM-DD.

you must trim out the time part of the .NET date type OR
you can use the Mysql DateTime DataType.

Answer (score 2):

Use [parameterized queries](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson06.aspx) instead. Your code is subject to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.